# Issue with MySQL query using PDO and OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I'm having a problem with my login script. I'm trying to make a method to make my mySQL query handling easier.

My code should return "OK!" to the page, but instead it returns "No user", which means that it counts 0 rows. I've tested the mySQL query on phpMyAdmin, and it works fine there.

My Code:

DB.php:

```
 public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
            if(count($where) === 3) {
                $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

                $field      = $where[0];
                $operator   = $where[1];
                $value      = $where[2];

                if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public function get($table, $where) {
            return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
        }

        public function count() {
            return $this->count;
        }
```

Index.php:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('digi_users.users', array('username', '=', 'chris')); 

                if(!$user->count()) {
                    echo 'No user';
                } else {
                    echo 'OK!';
                }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

### UPDATE

I'm establishing a database connection in my DB Class (DB.php).

I actually have multiple databases, so I created a couple connections.

Code in DB Class:

```
private function __construct() {
        /* Connect to DB 1 */
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db1'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        /* Connect to DB 2 */
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db2'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        /* Connect to DB 3 */
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db3'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        /* Connect to DB 4 */
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db4'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        /* Connect to DB 5 */
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db5'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        /* Connect to DB 6 */
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db6'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The `getInstance()` function creates a new DB instance.

Code from DB Class:

```
public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
```

`Query()` method from DB Class:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checkd a generated query? A result returned by `get`?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it. When I actually `print_r` the variable `$user` here, it outputs the correct information from the database, it just does not count it for some reason

Comment: SO, and what are you going to count in this variable? What's the implementation of `count()` for user object?

Comment: why in the last two weeks are there so many SO questions about **login scripts**? Is university starting off their Computing courses with login scripts?

Comment: I'm trying to write you an answer but there are too many unknowns and too many errors, this seems you don't have a properly working idea for how PDO or OOP works. I'm sorry. I will write my answer but it will not be great.

Comment: Hi, @Martin. I have updated my post with some more information. If you need any more, please let me know. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: yes, we need your `query` method/function of `DB` class

Comment: why `return self::$_instance;` you don't need to return the value, you need to save the value within your class to be used by the connections to the PDO. You should instead update `$this->_instance` and then use this as I have used `connection` in my code answer below

Comment: @Alex, I've updated my post with the `query()` method

Comment: @BroskyaP check my answer

Comment: @BroskyaP I have updated my answer

Comment: haha, @Alex snap :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your method :

```
public function count() {
     return $this->count;
}
```

versus:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    ...
    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
    ...
}
```

I guess you should change `count()` to:

```
public function count() {
     return $this->_count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that typo I guess.

Answer (score 1):

From your query method in your class you have this line:

```
 $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
```

so when you want to read the count value you can call it with

```
print $user->_count;
```

or have you made a getter method to return the `_count` value? if so you need to show that to us. Also helpful to yourself if you do a `var_dump` of the `$user` object to see what values and functions it holds.